# Is there any way to async post some data with twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

```
client.getPage('url', method='POST',
               postdata=urllib.urlencode({'doc': {somedata}}))
```

this isn't work for me and I got "empty data" in response. Seems postdata is just a joke

Comment: There is also the ``treq`` library it's similar to ``requests``.

Comment: Please use `treq`, or at least the thing that it is based on in Twisted, the new HTTP client in `Agent`: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html . `getPage` does not have secure `https` support, and will at some point be deprecated.

Comment: @Glyph Thx for the notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me in Python2 when I add `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
import urllib
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import client

client.getPage('http://requestb.in/vvs5qdvv', method='POST', 
               headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
               postdata=urllib.urlencode({'doc':'data'}));

reactor.run()
```

See sent data here: http://requestb.in/vvs5qdvv?inspect

Comment: Thank goodness.  You inspire me, I was just too rely on modules like `requests` to forget all I need is a header :)

Comment: Thanks for following up with your answer!